# [JAVA][HOMEWORK] Pickomino Game

Tags: java, arrays

Hey there guys and girls.
It's my first post here so be gentle if you can.

I have to create a Java Version of a board game called Pickomino. In this game, you are a chicken, you are throwing dice and you are collecting worms from the table. There are 16 cards on the table. If one player picks a card,he puts it in his "stack pile" and it's removed from table.

In my "main method" I have this code for getting points from the table but as you will see isn't 100% right, so I will like to hear your opinion, maybe with a better solution.

```
if (player1.canIPick(pickedDice)){
        switch (sumOfDice) {
            case 21:
            case 22:
            case 23:
            case 24:
                player1.setPoints(1);
                break;
            case 25:
            case 26:
            case 27:
            case 28:
                player1.setPoints(2);
                break;
            case 29:
            case 30:
            case 31:
            case 32:
                player1.setPoints(3);
                break;
            case 33:
            case 34:
            case 35:
            case 36:
                player1.setPoints(4);
                break;
        }
    }
```

There are 2 things that I don't like in this code, first, it's wrong cause if someone pick a card from the table and get the points, another player can pick the same card. 
Also like as I said, it's part of my main method and I don't like that, so I thought to create an **Array** in another class and have access from there into the cards but I am having a little trouble with this.
Is there any other suggestion that you can give me to help me?
Is Array gonna work or is it a wrong way too?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What exactly isn't working/right?  Your posted code does not refer to the cards you are speaking of in your question.

Comment: imagine the card with 2 numbers on it. The one number is the number that gives you access to the card, and it's the number in my *cases*. The number in *setPoint() method* is the number of points (=worms) that player gets. If I am player 1 and got a total of 25 points in dice I will get 2 points. If you got in your turn 25 points, in my code, you will get 2 points too. This is wrong. You cannot pick that card anymore from the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly how this game is played. 
But I would suggest on creating an array of cards that lie on the table, ( like you said).
And reset the values at the start of a new game.

```
ArrayList<Integer> cardsOnTable = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = minPoint; i<=maxPoint;i++) {
   cardsOnTable.add(i);
}
```

and when you remove a card you can check if that card is still on the table, (in the list).

```
if (player1.canIPick(pickedDice)){
    if(cardsOnTable.contains(sumOfDice)) {
       /* check for points here*/
       cardsOnTable.remove(sumOfDice));
    }
}
```

Or you can try using a HashMap with Integer and Boolean and have the boolean represent if the card is taken.

Comment: That sounds good. I will try it and I will come back. Thanks.